# Renaming database with Replicated Table

Tags: clickhouse

My Clickhouse database 'CurrDB' contains table with  engine type ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree.
I renamed this database to NewDB(Moved current tables to NewDB and deleted CurrDB).
Now when I tried to recreate same database('CurrDB') again and tried to create same tables (which were moved to NewDB) I gets error zookeeper node already exist. I am using zookeeper path '/product/DBName/tables/tableName'  with corresponding  DBName and tableName.

What should I do in rename operation so that I don't get conflict when creating same DB and tables again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZK path is constant string and cannot be changed.

`/product/DBName/tables/tableName` DBName , tableName and '/' are irrelevant. It just an abstraction. CH and ZK operate using this string without looking inside the string.

Just add some postfix to make different string
`/product/DBName/tables/tableName_v1`